# publish.php from bluerhinos returns Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mqtt, iot

here's the story line...

when open the publish.php it is perfectly working from byethost but
i get internal server error 500 from Hostinger.in

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: compare php versions and check php.ini files.

Comment: php7 them both, .ini file from hostinger is not accessible.